# foreach leaves out the very first value

Tags: php

I am processing a foreach(first) which gives the full array in the data, when I make another foreach(second) and pass the first foreach into second foreach the first value of the first foreach never appears in the second foreach. Does anyone have any idea why the foreach behaves this way? is there a solution for this?

I tried it this way no luck

```js
 $userIdsPerRoom = chatRoomUsersId($_SESSION['currentRoomID']);
 foreach ($userIdsPerRoom as $value) {
          $list[] =$value['UserID'];
         }
             
      foreach ($list as $value) {    
              $userInfo = chatRoomUsersEmail($value);
              foreach ($userInfo as $info) {
           
                echo $info['userEmail'];
              }
         }
     echo count($list);   ///gives the full list

 }
```

I noticed it with this code

```js
$userIdsPerRoom = chatRoomUsersId($_SESSION['currentRoomID']); //return an array of intergers with five values example array(1,2,3,4,5)
     foreach ($userIdsPerRoom as $value){
        $userInfo = chatRoomUsersEmail($value['UserID']);
        foreach ($userInfo as $info){
              echo $info['userEmail'];  /// I only get four values example array(b,c,d,e)
              }
 }
```

Comment: May be one of `$info ['userEmail']` is empty?

Comment: Try `echo empty( trim( $info ['userEmail'])) ? 'No email' : $info ['userEmail'];`